# Numpy average position without looping?

Tags: python, numpy

Assume I have a matrix which is N items long x M columns long (where M<=N). I want to know the average rank for each of the N across the M columns.

```
arr = np.array([
    [0,1],
    [2,0],
    [1,2]
])
```

I could loop through each of the N values and do something like the following, but I'm wondering whether there's a better approach to this

```
for n in range(3):
    np.where(arr==n)[0].mean()
```

**Edit**

Sorry, it seems my choice of example has caused some confusion. To better illustrate, let me swap in letters since the values in the matrix are identifiers, not numbers to be calculated on.

```
arr = np.array([
    ['A','B'],
    ['C','A'],
    ['B','C']
])
```

I am not trying to do a simple row-wise average. I'm trying to say that

- A average rank is 0.5 (0 + 1) / 2
- B average rank is 1.0 (0 + 2) / 2
- C average rank is 1.5 (1 + 2) / 2

Hopefully this clarified my request

Comment: Do you mean `np.mean(arr, axis=1)`?

Comment: What is _"average rank"_ please?

Comment: Why are you averaging indices of elements of array `arr` that are equal to some number `n`: `np.where(arr==n)[0].mean()`???

Comment: I added a clarification to show that I'm indeed averaging the indices because I want the average index value. I don't want the average of the value itself because those are just IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each of the `N` items appears exactly 1 time in each column, 
(i.e each column is a ranking) , you can simply do :

```
#arr = np.array([['A','B'],['C','A'],['B','C']])

means = arr.argsort(0).mean(1)
#array([ 0.5,  1. ,  1.5])
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to get the mean of your array along a certain axis. You can do this using the `axis=` argument of [`numpy.mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
    [0,1],
    [2,0],
    [1,2]
])

np.mean(arr, axis=1)
# [ 0.5  1.   1.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want row wise mean

```
>>> np.mean(arr, axis=1)
array([ 0.5,  1. ,  1.5])
```

To get rank (as OP's description)

First generate 2D array of indices

```
import numpy as  np

M = 5
N = 7

narray = np.array(np.tile(np.arange(N), M)).reshape(N, M)
print(narray)
```

Output:

```
[[0 1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 0 1 2]
 [3 4 5 6 0]
 [1 2 3 4 5]
 [6 0 1 2 3]
 [4 5 6 0 1]
 [2 3 4 5 6]]
```

Now take row wise mean to get rank

```
mean_value = np.mean(narray, axis=1)
print(mean_value)
```

Output

```
[ 2.   2.8  3.6  3.   2.4  3.2  4. ]
```

Comment: Your result should not change when `narray` is scaled. Check that *that* is the case when `narray *= 10`, for example.

Comment: Why are you multiplying narray with 10. narrray contains value of range [0-6]

Comment: I added a clarification to show that I'm indeed averaging the indices because I want the average index value. I don't want the average of the value itself because those are just IDs.  - OP said this. What's the conclusion here?

Comment: The idea is that "mean rank" (as called by OP) is *independent* of the values of the array `arr` (OP) or `narray` (your notation). The end result should depend *only on relative positions* of values. Therefore, by multiplying `narray` by any constant (non-zero) factor we get a "different" array whose unique values occupy the same positions as the unique values in the original (non-scaled) array. Therefore, for both arrays, average rank must be the same.

Comment: @ElPresidente What is your opinion? Am I mis-understanding your problem?

Comment: If he deals with relative position, you are right. If he deals with value in range [0 - N-1], mine one will work too. right?

Comment: Op said "I want the average index value". In your case, average of `[ 0 10 20 30 40]` will be 2.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see what is the connection between OP's `arr` and your `narray` and how to get from one to another.

Comment: I think only OP can tell what he is actually asking. Lets wait

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt to "improve" your original solution. My solution has the benefit of not needing to perform two (possibly very time consuming) operations all over again for each value in the array: `np.where(arr==n)` (1. find all values equal to `n`; 2. find indices of elements for which previous equality is true).

```
values, inverse, counts = np.unique(arr, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
rows = np.argsort(inverse) // len(arr[0])
cumsum = np.cumsum(counts)
avranks = np.add.reduceat(rows, cumsum - cumsum[0]) / counts
```

Then, for your original data,

```
>>> print(avranks)
[0.5 1.  1.5]
```

Comment: For `[[0 1],[0 1],[0 1]]`, getting output `[ 0.33333333  0.66666667]`.  OP requires row-wise average. That means output should contain 3 value.s  See. Only OP can clarify his question.

Comment: `[[0 5],[2 3],[4 1]]` -> output `[ 0.  5.  2.  3.  4.  1.]`. Whats really happening here?

Comment: @aerokite Good catch! I fixed my mistake: it should have been `rows` instead of `inverse` in the last line (which is why I was computing `rows` in the first place!) With this fix, the answer for your previous example should be: `array([0., 2., 1., 1., 2., 0.])`